# Invoking a generic function with a type variable conforming to a protocol

Tags: swift, generics

In a generic function, I want to test if a given object conforming to a certain protocol is of a given type. It works great if a concrete class type is passed as a parameter to the checking function. However, when I use a variable for the type (using ternary operator), I get an error:

> Cannot invoke '`isObject`' with an argument list of type '`(AnyObject, of: P.Type)`'

Casting additionally the type variable to `P.Protocol` doesn't help either, since:

> In argument type '`P.Protocol`', '`P`' does not conform to expected type '`P`'

```
protocol P {
    static var descr: String {get}
}

class A: P {
    static let descr = "class A"
}

class B: P {
    static let descr = "class B"
}

class Test {
    func isObject<T:P>(_ object: AnyObject, of type: T.Type) -> Bool {
        print("descr: \(type.descr)")
        return object is T
    }
}

let a = A()
let type = (false ? A.self : B.self) as P.Type //as! P.Protocol
let test = Test()

test.isObject(a, of: type)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with a generic placeholder `T`, when `T` is a protocol type `P`, `T.Type` is `P.Protocol` *not* `P.Type`. In other words, it takes a metatype that describes the protocol *itself* rather than a metatype that describes a type that conforms to the protocol. This distinction is important because [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878).

One solution in your case is to introduce a wrapper around a `P.Type` metatype which uses a generic placeholder in the initialiser in order to store a closure to perform the `is` check for you.

```
struct AnyPType {

    let base: P.Type
    private let _isInstance: (Any) -> Bool

    /// Creates a new AnyType wrapper from a given metatype.
    /// The passed metatype's value **must** match its static value, i.e `T.self == base`.
    init<T : P>(_ base: T.Type) {
        precondition(T.self == base, "The static value \(T.self) and dynamic value \(base) of the passed metatype do not match")
        self.base = T.self
        self._isInstance = { $0 is T }
    }

    func isInstance(_ instance: Any) -> Bool {
        return _isInstance(instance)
    }
}
```

This is a specialised version of the wrapper that I show in my answer [to this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44874126/2976878), in which I also show how to lift the limitation of `T.self == base` on Apple platforms (but this limitation shouldn't be a problem in your case).

You can now use the wrapper like so:

```
class Test {
    func isObject(_ object: Any, of type: AnyPType) -> Bool {
        print("descr: \(type.base.descr)")
        return type.isInstance(object)
    }
}

let type = AnyPType(A.self) // or AnyPType(B.self)

print(Test().isObject(A(), of: type))

// descr: class A
// true
```