# Size of Any.Type in swift

Tags: swift

I have a problem of getting the size of a variable declared as `Any.Type`

See the following playground code:

I have this function:

```
func genericSizeMe<T> (_ : T.Type) -> Int
{
    return MemoryLayout<T>.size
}
```

I run it like this:

```
let size1 = genericSizeMe(UInt32.self) // 4
let size2 = genericSizeMe(UInt16.self) // 2

var type1: UInt32.Type = UInt32.self
let size3 = genericSizeMe(type1) // 4

var type2: UInt16.Type = UInt16.self
let size4 = genericSizeMe(type2) // 2


var type3: Any.Type = UInt32.self
let size5 = genericSizeMe(type3) //ERROR
```

This gives the error:

```
/*

 Playground execution failed:

 error: MyPlayground.playground:14:13: error: cannot invoke 'genericSizeMe' with an argument list of type '(Any.Type)'
 let size5 = genericSizeMe(type3)
 ^

 MyPlayground.playground:14:13: note: expected an argument list of type '(T.Type)'
 let size5 = genericSizeMe(type3)
 ^

 */
```

How (if possible) would one solve this? What I want to achieve is to have an array of types, and get the size of each type. Like this:

```
[UInt32.self, UInt8.self]
```

And loop over the array and print the byte size needed to allocate each type.

---

If easier, I can also accept to actually make an instance of each type before getting the size.

Comment: Just curious here; why?

Comment: I'm writing a parser for a protocol. It's sending an arbitary length of bytes, and I want to parse it dynamically... Or rather, I want to specify how it should be parsed by using some arrays with types like i showed

Comment: Oh. I'm not qualified to give you a full answer on this one, but while I tried to find something for you I stumbled over this; https://academy.realm.io/posts/goto-mike-ash-exploring-swift-memory-layout/ - looks like it might be relevant for you.

Comment: @ullstrm Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you're relying on the memory layouts of various types; note that this generally isn't a safe assumption to make, as memory layout is usually an implementation detail, and therefore subject to change (the resilience changes coming up soon should help with this though). It will be a safe assumption to make for `@_fixed_layout` stdlib types after ABI stability though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're running into with your generic function is that [when a generic placeholder `T` is a protocol type `P`, `T.Type` is not `P.Type`; it's `P.Protocol`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234233/2976878).

You cannot therefore pass an `Any.Type` to a `T.Type` parameter (although `Any` isn't technically a protocol, it's a special built-in type; it has the semantics of a protocol in most cases). You need to pass a metatype that represents a concrete type.

Therefore one solution is to build a type-erasing wrapper for metatypes, as shown in [Check whether Swift object is an instance of a given metatype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44874126/2976878):

```
struct AnyType {

  let base: Any.Type
  private let _memorySize: () -> Int
  private let _memoryStride: () -> Int
  private let _memoryAlignment: () -> Int

  var memorySize: Int { return _memorySize() }
  var memoryStride: Int { return _memoryStride() }
  var memoryAlignment: Int { return _memoryAlignment() }

  /// Creates a new AnyType wrapper from a given metatype.
  /// The passed metatype's value **must** match its static value,
  /// i.e `T.self == base` must be `true`.
  init<T>(_ base: T.Type) {
    precondition(T.self == base, """
      The static value \(T.self) and dynamic value \(base) of the \
      passed metatype do not match
      """
    )
    self.base = T.self
    self._memorySize = { MemoryLayout<T>.size }
    self._memoryStride = { MemoryLayout<T>.stride }
    self._memoryAlignment = { MemoryLayout<T>.alignment }
  }
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
struct S {
  var i: Int
  var b: Bool
}

let types = [AnyType(UInt32.self), AnyType(UInt8.self), AnyType(S.self)]

for type in types {
  print("Size of \(type.base): \(type.memorySize)")
  print("Stride of \(type.base): \(type.memoryStride)")
  print("Alignment of \(type.base): \(type.memoryAlignment)")
  print()
}

//  Size of UInt32: 4
//  Stride of UInt32: 4
//  Alignment of UInt32: 4
//
//  Size of UInt8: 1
//  Stride of UInt8: 1
//  Alignment of UInt8: 1
//
//  Size of S: 9
//  Stride of S: 16
//  Alignment of S: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I got inspiration from HandyJSON.

```
protocol AnyExtensions {}

extension AnyExtensions {
    public static func getSize() -> Int {
        return MemoryLayout<Self>.size;
    }
}

func extensions(of type: Any.Type) -> AnyExtensions.Type {
    struct Extensions : AnyExtensions {}
    var extensions: AnyExtensions.Type = Extensions.self
    withUnsafePointer(to: &extensions) { pointer in
        UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: pointer).assumingMemoryBound(to: Any.Type.self).pointee = type
    }
    return extensions
}
```

Just call like this to get the correct result:

```
extensions(of: type).getSize()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

To get size of any type dynamically you can use next approach with protocol type container:

```swift
protocol Accessor {}
extension Accessor {
    static var size: Int {
        MemoryLayout<Self>.size
    }
}

struct ProtocolTypeContainer {
    let type: Any.Type
    let witnessTable = 0
}

func size(of type: Any.Type) -> Int {
    let container = ProtocolTypeContainer(type: type)
    return unsafeBitCast(container, to: Accessor.Type.self).size
}
```

How to use:

```swift
size(of: Int8.self) // 1
size(of: Int16.self) // 2
size(of: Int32.self) // 4
size(of: Int.self) // 8
size(of: String.self) // 16
```