# How do I filter view controller by type?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my simple function:

```
func popTo<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type, from context: UINavigationController?) {
    let mytype = type
    guard let controller = context?.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is T }) else {
        return
    }
    print(mytype) //1
    print(context?.viewControllers) //2
    print(controller) //3
    context?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

After I put a breakpoint and print out the following lines, I get console output:

```
PLZ.GroupViewController //1

▿ Optional<Array<UIViewController>> //2
  ▿ some : 5 elements
    ▿ 0 : <PLZ.GroupsViewController: 0x11dd68660>
    ▿ 1 : <PLZ.GroupViewController: 0x11f415c70>
    ▿ 2 : <PLZ.ProductViewController: 0x11f619d00>
    ▿ 3 : <PLZ.ConfirmViewController: 0x11f538cd0>
    ▿ 4 : <PLZ.ConfirmationViewController: 0x11f53e330>

<PLZ.GroupsViewController: 0x11dd68660> //3
```

Why it returns `GroupsViewController` when it should `GroupViewController`?

How do I call that function?

```
if let type = viewModel.returnControllerType {
    print(type) //4
    self?.router.popTo(type: type, from: self?.navigationController)
} 

PLZ.GroupViewController //4
```

`returnControllerType` is defined:

```
let returnControllerType: UIViewController.Type?
```

Comment: Is there a inheritance between `GroupViewController` & `GroupsViewController`?

Comment: no, both of them inherit directly from `UIViewController`

Comment: I suppose it searchs for UIViewController, not for GroupViewController. Is there a way to check it for type parameter?

Comment: How are you calling this `popTo` function?

Comment: Great, that confirms my suspicion. The generic type parameter `T` is inferred as `UIViewController`, so the `is` check is checking `is UIViewController`. You need a way to check whether an `Any` is of the type represented by a given `Any.Type` (`returnControllerType` in your code). [This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44875557/5133585)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution ever is:

```
func popTo<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type, from context: UINavigationController?) {
    guard let controller = context?.viewControllers.first(where: { $0.isKind(of: type) }) else {
        return
    }
    context?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```